# Yii2 NavBar - which property to add class to navbar-header?

Tags: yii2, navbar

I've included some of the default Yii2 output below for reference.

```
<nav id="w0" class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
       ...
```

The code I have is...

```
NavBar::begin([
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
    'brandOptions'=>[
        'class'=>'page-scroll'
    ],
    ...
]);
```

which outputs...

```
<nav id="w0" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
       ...
```

The `brandOptions` are applied, as desired, to the brand link later in the output. The output I'm seeking is...

```
<nav id="w0" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
       ...
```

I'm wanting to add a class to the 2nd div there, the one that gets "navbar-header" but for all my attempts I haven't been able to identify the property to apply it on. Any tips?

Thanks in advance,
Pedro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css  should be

```
 nav > .container > .navbar-header {

   .... set you css  style 


 }
```

or you could do directly

```
<div class="navbar-header   you_class">
```

for settig the navabar widget      You can use options this way eg:

```
    NavBar::begin([

            'options' => [
                 'class' => 'navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top',
            ],
            'innerContainerOptions' => [
                 'class' => 'navbar-header',
            ],
    ]);
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is the property on Yii2 NavBar widget on which to add the class with `$options = ['class'=>'my_class']`.

Comment: That puts the class on the `nav` element. My edit to the question should make what I'm after clearer.

Comment: I have update the answer  hope is what you are looking for  .. anyway you can refer to this doc for navbar config http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-navbar.html

Comment: `innerContainerOptions` hits the div that gets `class="container"` by default. I'm wanting to add a class on the div nested inside that one.

Comment: If is not innerContainerOptions   then try   containerOptions or clientOptions   .. these are the param in DOC.. otherwise  no others .are available  .. and you shuld use css or  jquery .. for add .. hope all this is at least useful ..

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried the Jquery route to no avail, so have gone with doing the `NavBar` in HTML with the inner `Nav` element a Yii code. Curiously `page-scroll ` doesn't appear anywhere in the CSS, but it's presence at that point in the page makes a world of difference.